# Deformation retract on subspace of $S^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, retraction

Let $M = \{(x, y, 0, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^4 ~|~ x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ and $N = \{(0, 0, z, w) \in \mathbb{R}^4 ~|~ z^2 + w^2 = 1\}$ be subspaces of $S^3$. Construct a deformation retract of $S^3 \setminus M$ onto $N$, or show one does not exist.

**Progress:**

I was thinking something like the family of maps $t \in [0, 1]$ defined by
$$ r_t(x, y, z, w) = \left (\sqrt{1 - t^2}x, \sqrt{1 - t^2}y, z, w \right ) $$
but the image is not on the sphere.

Comment: What about $\Bbb R^3-\{z\text{-axis}\}$ deformation retracting to the unit circle in the $xy$-plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f_t : S^3 \setminus M \to S^3 \setminus M$ by $$f_t(x,y,z,w) = \frac{(tx,ty,z,w)}{\|(tx,ty,z,w)\|}.$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*. Every $p$ not on $M$ or $N$ is uniquely expressible as $p=\cos(\theta)m+\sin(\theta)n$ for points $m\in M$, $n\in N$ and convex angle $\theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. IOW all $p$ lie on an arc between points of $M$ and $N$.

BTW, fixing $\theta$ and allowing $m\in M,n\in N$ to vary yields a Clifford torus.

This hint illustrates the fact $S^3=S^1\ast S^1$ is a topological *join* of two Hopf circles. If we stereographically project $S^3$ using a pole through one of the circles, that circle is projected to an axis, and the other circle to a circle around that line. If we form a 2D cross-section through the axis, the other circle intersects it in two points, and if we draw all the arcs between the two points and the line, as well as draw all circles of constant $\theta$, we get *bipolar coordinates*.

Comment: For $(x, y, z, w) \in \mathbb{R}^4$, let $a = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $b = \sqrt{z^2 + w^2}$. Then we can express the point as $\cos(\theta)\left(\frac{x}{a}, \frac{y}{a}, 0, 0\right) + \sin(\theta)\left(0, 0, \frac{z}{b}, \frac{w}{b}\right)$, where $\theta = \arccos{a} = \arcsin{b}$; uniquness is obvious. Should this proof give me insight on how to solve the problem? Because I still don't see it.

Comment: Yes, it should provide insight. Slide points along the arcs.

Comment: So you're saying to slide $p$ to $n$. I'm not so sure what the "points in between" are supposed to be though. Also, when $p \in N$ we do not have such a decomposition, so I guess it has to take that into account.

Comment: We do have such a decomposition, it's just that $m\in M$ isn't unique (which won't matter). Namely: $n=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})m+\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})n$ with $m\in M$ arbitrary. The arc between $m$ and $n$ is all the points $p=\cos(\theta)m+\sin(\theta)n$ for $0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$. Can you show $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ deformation retracts onto $\{\frac{\pi}{2}\}$? Same thing for $S^3$, but simultaneously in each arc. The $S^2$ version of this, BTW, is that $S^2$ minus the equator def. ret. onto the N/S poles, and $S^2$ minus the N/S poles def. ret. onto the equator. Can you visualize these?